# New articles defaulting to home page

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I'm adding on to a Joomla 1.5 website. When I add a new article and assign it to a section/category, I then add to the main menu. On the frontend, when clicking that link, it only shows the home page content and not the article content. Here is the website and the link is under "About Us" as "Test Form":

http://rocketship1.thehostingcompany.us/~hyp/

Any ideas what's going on? Thanks!

Here's query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM jos_session 
  WHERE session_id = 't6uabsp4oh7gnvpitgm3rcro27'
DELETE 
  FROM jos_session 
  WHERE ( TIME < '1339531072' )
SELECT * 
  FROM jos_session 
  WHERE session_id = 't6uabsp4oh7gnvpitgm3rcro27'
UPDATE `jos_session` 
  SET `time`='1339534672',`userid`='0',`usertype`='',`username`='',`gid`='0',`guest`='1',`client_id`='0',`data`='__default|a:7:{s:15:\"session.counter\";i:55;s:19:\"session.timer.start\";i:1339527526;s:18:\"session.timer.last\";i:1339534666;s:17:\"session.timer.now\";i:1339534667;s:22:\"session.client.browser\";s:106:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5\";s:8:\"registry\";O:9:\"JRegistry\":3:{s:17:\"_defaultNameSpace\";s:7:\"session\";s:9:\"_registry\";a:1:{s:7:\"session\";a:1:{s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}}}s:7:\"_errors\";a:0:{}}s:4:\"user\";O:5:\"JUser\":19:{s:2:\"id\";i:0;s:4:\"name\";N;s:8:\"username\";N;s:5:\"email\";N;s:8:\"password\";N;s:14:\"password_clear\";s:0:\"\";s:8:\"usertype\";N;s:5:\"block\";N;s:9:\"sendEmail\";i:0;s:3:\"gid\";i:0;s:12:\"registerDate\";N;s:13:\"lastvisitDate\";N;s:10:\"activation\";N;s:6:\"params\";N;s:3:\"aid\";i:0;s:5:\"guest\";i:1;s:7:\"_params\";O:10:\"JParameter\":7:{s:4:\"_raw\";s:0:\"\";s:4:\"_xml\";N;s:9:\"_elements\";a:0:{}s:12:\"_elementPath\";a:1:{i:0;s:83:\"C:\\BitNami WAMPStack\\apps\\joomla\\htdocs\\HYP\\libraries\\joomla\\html\\parameter\\element\";}s:17:\"_defaultNameSpace\";s:8:\"_default\";s:9:\"_registry\";a:1:{s:8:\"_default\";a:1:{s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":0:{}}}s:7:\"_errors\";a:0:{}}s:9:\"_errorMsg\";N;s:7:\"_errors\";a:0:{}}}' 
  WHERE session_id='t6uabsp4oh7gnvpitgm3rcro27'
SELECT * 
  FROM jos_components 
  WHERE parent = 0
SELECT folder AS TYPE, element AS name, params 
  FROM jos_plugins 
  WHERE published >= 1 
  AND access <= 0 
  ORDER BY ordering
SHOW COLUMNS 
  FROM jos_content
SELECT template 
  FROM jos_templates_menu 
  WHERE client_id = 0 
  AND (menuid = 0 OR menuid = 117) 
  ORDER BY menuid DESC 
  LIMIT 0, 1
SELECT * 
  FROM `jos_rsform_config`
SELECT id, title, module, POSITION, content, showtitle, control, params 
  FROM jos_modules AS m 
  LEFT JOIN jos_modules_menu AS mm 
  ON mm.moduleid = m.id 
  WHERE m.published = 1 
  AND m.access <= 0 
  AND m.client_id = 0 
  AND ( mm.menuid = 117 OR mm.menuid = 0 ) 
  ORDER BY POSITION, ordering
```

Comment: Very odd...obcviously the menu item is published, are you certain that the section, category, and article are also published?

Comment: All the others seem to be working as expected, i can only suggest you look at the various parameters for that particular article - sorry I can't give you a real answer :/

Comment: I have copied that article from a working article. I'm guessing once the article is copied, it has all the same parameters as the original?

Comment: Ah...in that case, it might be an alias of whatever you copied.  Best bet is to create a new menu link....Menu Itemids are the nerve center of Joomla -always want to have them right.

Comment: This was the other steps I took. Created new article and assigned it to a section/category (both are published). Added to the Main Menu as Article Layout. Was there something else I needed to do?

Comment: Sounds like you did everything right...I'm baffled.  If you have access to the database itself, i'd be looking at table jos_menu, record id#113 (I think it was) and comparing that to another id that's working.  I can't see anything you've done wrong.

Comment: The only thing I see different with that to one that is working is the "Published" column. The ones that work are showing 1 and id#113 is showing -2. There also is no parent set on the ones that are not working. It's showing 0. Would that cause anything?

Comment: That might be it, but I don't know which IDs have been created, deleted, etc.  the -2 means that it's been archived, but I seldom use archiving ,so can't say for sure how it would appear.  I'd change that to 1, saying it's published - my money is on that doing the trick though.

Comment: Nevermind. That did nothing. This is frustrating. Been looking at this for 2 days now.

Comment: Do you have any rewriting going on for SEO such as SH404 - maybe something is being cached...(sorry -normally pretty handy with this stuff).

Comment: The only thing I have is the basic SEO friendly URL set to yes under global config. Mod_rewrite is set to No. Cache and debug is set to off.

Comment: I was able to create a new article under another theme and it works perfectly so it must be theme specific. Any idea where I should look in the theme? Thanks for your help.

Comment: God only knows on that one - they're all built with their own rules - a good question for the authors of that theme though.

Comment: I turned on debugging and looked at the sql query. When clicking the top level of that menu, it shows one query. Then when you click a 2nd tiered link, it shows another query. However, when you click on the new article link, which is a 2nd tiered link, it shows the top level query. It doesn't pull any published times, dates, IDs etc. This seems like the problem. Any idea where that query is pulling from?

Comment: What is the query that's returning no results?

Comment: Ooops, thought this was another joomla question...so my "out of ideas" commment doesn't apply.

Comment: Working from the debugging SQL though....copy/paste that list of sql statements somewhere, then do the same thing on another menu item THAT USES THAT SAME FORM component and DOES display properly - I'm trying to identify what query is failing, that isn't showing up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consolidating all we know into an answer here:

From your menu, this does **not** work:

[index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=102&Itemid=113](http://rocketship1.thehostingcompany.us/~hyp/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=102&Itemid=113)

But simply changing the Itemid to a random, but valid one **DOES** work:

[index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=102&Itemid=50](http://rocketship1.thehostingcompany.us/~hyp/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=102&Itemid=50)

This indicates to me that data in your jos_menu and/or jos_menu_type tables are suspect because using the random Itemid 50 ignores whatever the settings are that you've set up for Menu Itemid 113.

What Component is the menu item - just a standard article? How does RSForms get incorporated into the whole equation I've never used rsforms) - using {loadposition xxx}?

Comment: Hey Greg, thanks for all your help. The component is just a standard new article. I'm not sure how rsform is used. I took this site over from another developer and I haven't messed with the rsforms yet. I didn't use them on any articles. I've looked at the tables you mentioned but not sure what I'm looking for in there. Everything looks fine.

Comment: Ok, here's what I did. I created a new article and menu link with itemid of 118. I then changed that and went down to see where it would start working. ItemId 100-118 never worked. 99 and below did. It seems like all triple digit ItemIds don't show the article content. Would this be a setting somewhere?

Comment: Got it working now. I couldn't find the cause of the reason why anything over ItemID 99 wouldn't link up so I am now just creating new menu links as external links with a changed ItemID like so

http://localhost/joomla/hyp/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=104&Itemid=99

instead of

http://localhost/joomla/hyp/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=104&Itemid=118

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now. I couldn't find the cause of the reason why anything over ItemID 99 wouldn't link up so I am now just creating new menu links as external links with a changed ItemID like so

article&id=104&Itemid=99

instead of

article&id=104&Itemid=118

Comment: Well thank God for that...curious about what is causing such a situation, but glad you're up and running one way or another!  Happy to have at least been a fresh set of eyes to work through it.